# How to use reduce with lambda to put each word in a js array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, reduce, higher-order-functions

Output should look like this:[[],[],[],[],[4 letter words], [5 letter words], [6 letter words], ... [20 letter words]. I created an array with 21 empty subarrays and I'm trying to push the words in from a different array called wordArray.

```
let acc = []
let i = 0
while ( i < 21){ // creating array with 21 empty subarrays
    acc.push([])
    i++
}

let reducer = function(acc, key) {
    return acc = wordArray.reduce(function(acc, word) {
    (acc[word[key]] = acc[word[key]] || [] ).push(word)
    //acc.push(word)
    return acc
    }, [])
};
console.log(reducer(acc, 'length'));
```

My code pushes the words into arrays depending on the word length but it needs to also add empty subarrays depending word.length starting at zero and going through the 21st slot of the acc array. For example there are no words being stored that are less than 4 letters long, so the array should hold 4 empty arrays [] as well as empty arrays for words up to length 21.

Comment: What does `wordArray` look like?

Comment: wordArray is an array of words read in from txt file. It strips \r and \n, so just the words

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a lot easier to approach by removing the confusion of `reduce`, the code is a lot clearer if you just iterate over the words and push/assign to indicies of `acc` in a loop:

```js
const wordArray = ['foobar'];

let acc = []
let i = 0
while (i < 21) {
  acc.push([])
  i++
}

let reducer = function(acc, key) {
  for (const word of wordArray) {
    (acc[word[key]] = acc[word[key]] || []).push(word)
  }
  return acc;
};
console.log(reducer(acc, 'length'));
```

If you really wanted to use `reduce`, make sure to pass in the `acc` you constructed into it as the initial value for the accumulator (right now you're passing in an initial accumulator of `[]`, not the multidimensional array)

```js
const wordArray = ['foobar'];

let acc = []
let i = 0
while (i < 21) { // creating array with 21 empty subarrays
  acc.push([])
  i++
}

let reducer = function(acc, key) {
  return acc = wordArray.reduce(function(acc, word) {
    (acc[word[key]] = acc[word[key]] || []).push(word)
    //acc.push(word)
    return acc
  }, acc)
};
console.log(reducer(acc, 'length'));
```

Comment: So I was pretty close but not quite there. This worked how I wanted it to! Thank you!